# Plot doesn't show all categories

Tags: python

```
keep_origin = ['Cooking Area or Kitchen', 
              'Porch or Balcony', 
              'Sleeping Area or Bedroom (inc. patients room, dormitory, etc)',
              'Trash, Rubbish Storage (inc garbage chute room, garbage/industri',
              'Living Area (e.g. living, TV, recreation, etc)',
              'Garage',
              'Roof',
              'Laundry Area',
              'Washroom or Bathroom (toilet,restroom/locker room)',
              'Chimney/Flue Pipe',
              'Engine Area',
              'Trash, rubbish area (outside)',
              'Mechanical/Electrical Services Room',
              'Basement/cellar (not partitioned)',
              'Exterior Wall',
              'Other Outside Area',
              'Hallway, Corridor',
              'Electrical Systems',
              'HVAC Equipment Room (furnace room, water heater closet, boiler)',
              'Court, Patio, Terrace',
              'Attached Deck']

for i in df['Area_of_Origin']:
    if i not in keep_origin:
        df['Area_of_Origin'] = np.where((df.Area_of_Origin == i), 'Other', df.Area_of_Origin)
        
        #The remaining categories
        
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df['Area_of_Origin'].value_counts())
    
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,13
df['Area_of_Origin'].value_counts(ascending=True).plot(kind='barh')
```

The code is working properly the only thing is (Washroom or Bathroom (toilet,restroom/locker room) and (roof) count don't appear on the plot

[image: Plot]

Comment: We can't tell where the problem is, because for all we know, those values simply don't exist in `df`.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain ..... i'm trying to group all categories with less observations (less than 100 ) then assign the rest of the category to a new 'Other' category. the entire thing working properly the only issue as i mentioned (Washroom or Bathroom (toilet,restroom/locker room) and (roof) count don't appear on the plot even that their observations are more than hundred. i hope it is clear now

Comment: "even that their observations are more than hundred.": that is what you say, and while I'm inclined to believe that, the simplest solution to your problem is that that is not true. There may be a space difference, capitalization etc, but the simplest explanation is that these values are not present (or not enough) that they will show up in the final figure. Without proof to the contrary, and without seeing any obvious defect in the code, that's my suggestion.

Comment: Note that your example is not a [mcve]: it is not self contained, since df (potentially in a smaller form) is not provided (nor are, e.g., the relevant imports, but those are common enough that people can provide that. We can't, however, provide the actual data).